# PHP Dropbox API download file to server

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I'm attempting to download file from dropbox to my server, nothing is returned but i know the file exists

```
$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token,
                        'Content-Type: application/json',
                        'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path": "'.$filepath.'"}');

        $file = fopen($filename, "w+");

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        
        curl_close ($ch);

        fclose($file);
```

Where did i go wrong?  How do i solve?

Comment: $error_msg = curl_error($ch); Can you print $error_msg  variable and check if there is any error?

Comment: what was the output of `$result` and where you can use it?

Comment: no error returned and the output of `$result` is `1`?

Comment: you have read permission of that file of dropbox?

Comment: Also, "application/json" is the wrong "Content-Type" for [/2/files/download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download). That header for this call should be omitted or set to something like "application/octet-stream".

Answer (score 0):

try this way and check the output of the result. and save it to the local server.

```
$url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download';
        
$formData = [
    "path"=> $filepath
];

$ch = curl_init($url);
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token;
$request_data = "Dropbox-API-Arg: ".json_encode($formData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorization, $request_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
dd($result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Content-Type: application/octet-stream header not the json header.

```
$requestData = [
    'path' => $filepath,
];
$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token,
                    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
                    'Dropbox-API-Arg: '.json_encode($requestData));

$file = fopen($filename, "w+");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
    
curl_close ($ch);

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Your code missed your answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).